# IDEA PyCharm .py works while .ipynb not

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

In VirtEnv I got simple `numpy/np-array.py` that contains simple call:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array(1)
```

When I run `python np-array.py` in PyCharm it runs ok. It is also ok when I run the same as ipynb cell in jupyter notebook web interface.

However in PyCharm  I connecting to jupyter notebook server with its token but I got:
[image]

PyCharm uses VirtEnv for python and numpy. Jupyter is installed system -wide outside this virtual env.

Question:

How to make PyCharm use th jupyter?

Comment: if you want to run the code in your juypter notebook, you will need to export it as a .py file, you can then open that up in pycharm

Comment: @Lingster no, I want to run ipynb in PyCharm connected to local `jupyter notebook` server

Comment: ah, in that case I think this tutorial solves your problem:https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html  - which version of pycharm are you using? recommend using 2017.2 or official instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-ipython-jupyter-notebook-cells.html

Comment: @Lingster wiered when I start Jupyter according to this tutorial from within pycharm it works ok but when I try to connect to jupyter instance run from outside pycharm (ie in terminal) I got this error.